# Which is better LinkedBlockingQueue unbounded or LinkedBlockingQueue with capacity

Tags: java, multithreading, queue, threadpoolexecutor

I am using LinkedBlockingQueue as workqueue in ThreadPoolExecutor. Problem is shall i use bounded LinkedBlockingQueue or unbounded LinkedBlockingQueue. I have overridden execute method of ThreadPoolExecutor and no longer facing the problem of thread creation after core pool size.

So please tell me which will be better one to use LinkedBlockingQueue bounded or unbounded.

Thanks,
Tushar

Comment: Posting the relevant code might help us with your answer

Comment: If you need a bounded , use bounded , if not , use an unbounded !
What is your mean for **better** ?Both of them are one thing , on thing is bounded and another is unbounded !
Please clarify your question :)

Comment: Better means in terms of CPU usage, memory usage and throughput i.e. overall efficiency. 
Whether poll and offer operations have different performance stats on bounded and unbounded linked blocking queue?

Comment: There's no apparent reason to think either would be better in those terms. It comes down to which behaviour you *need.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unbounded queue is secure way to ensure no task is rejected, or use bounded queue with such a capacity that is so large that it is capable of holding maximum number of tasks that can come in your application. That depends on design of your application. I think if you understand(discuss with architect) application design, you would be able to decide upon size of queue. And about memory and CPU, unless you add tasks to the queue, they wont increase, and will be same for both - unbounded or bounded. (Tested in demo application)

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
   LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable> r = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(11);

  while(true)
  {
     //    r.offer(new Task(1));
  }
}
```

just play around with size to check.

Answer (score 4):

An unbounded `LinkedBlockingQueue` is basically a bounded queue with a capacity of `java.lang.Integer.MAX_VALUE`. So yes, as mentioned in the comments, use a bounded or a unbounded queue based on your needs and not for performance since the size checks happen irrespective of you specify the limit or not.

As always, if you know the capacity in advance, I would recommend profiling an unbounded queue usage against a bounded one with the given capacity though I would not recommend going that route unless you have proof that the queue is the one causing performance issues in your application.

Answer (score 2):

If you can estimate how much maximum number of pending items can be in queue, better will be to use bounded queue. Threads which insert items in queue can know if queue is full after estimated queue size.

This all depends on task you want to perform. If you want to make threads which insert items in queue to wait after maximum number of pending items in queue, you should consider bounded queue.

Bounded queues will be better in terms of memory and CPU, as only at most bounded number of items can be in queue (memory benefit), and will make threads which insert items in queue to wait if queue is full (CPU benefit). Overall performance will be improved.

**This will have big advantage when rate of queuing in queue is not equal to rate of  dequeuing.**